# Is $\Bbb Q$ intersect $[0,1]$ in $\Bbb R$ compact?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, compactness

A subset is compact iff it is closed and bounded.

I know $[0,1]$ is closed in $\Bbb R$, and the intersection of two closed sets is closed. I don’t know if $\Bbb Q$ is open or closed in $\Bbb R$ and have seen proofs for both.

Comment: Q is dense in R, so sqrt2 × R is also dense in R, so ....

Comment: A set is closed if and only if its complement is open. So if you have a point that does not lie in $X$ (the set you are inquiring), does there exist an $\varepsilon$-neighborhood that shares no point with $X$? Hint: Between any two irrational numbers is a rational number.

Comment: You have seen proofs that $\mathbb{Q}$ is open or closed in $\mathbb{R}$? That's very interesting because it is neither.

Comment: @freakish: No, they saw proofs that it is *both* open and closed.

Answer (score 4):

The set $\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,1]$ is bounded, but it is not closed (and therefore not compact). For instance, each number of the form $\left(1-\frac1n\right)^n$ belongs to it, but $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1-\frac1n\right)^n=\frac1e\notin\mathbb Q$.

Answer (score 2):

The set $\mathbb Q\cap [0,1]$ is not compact, because it is not closed.

To see this let $a\in [0,1]\setminus\mathbb Q$, i.e., an irrational in $[0,1]$.
Then the sequence
$$
a_n=\frac{\lfloor na\rfloor}{n},\,\,n\in\mathbb N,
$$
is a sequence of rationals in $[0,1]$, and $a_n\to a$,
since
$$
na-1<\lfloor na\rfloor\le na \quad\Longrightarrow\quad
a-\frac{1}{n}=\frac{na-1}{n}<a_n=\frac{\lfloor na\rfloor}{n}\le \frac{na}{n}=a.
$$

**Note.** $\mathbb Q$ is neither closed nor open.